# Div of same style but variable color

Tags: css

I am writing an HTML page for private purposes that should display the content of a matrix in a graphical way. Essentially, I have a table made of divs, and each of the cells has a shape. I took, for example, the triangle shapes from here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_shapes.asp. As you can see in their example, the background color of the div is encoded in the style definition of the div.

What I would like to do now is to have the same shape everywhere in all cells, but change the color arbitrarily. What I could do is to make two divs with the same style definitions but then only separate lines for where the color is involved. But the point is, I have an arbitrary amount of different colors (it actually depends on the matrix), thus, this approach is not preferrable.

Instead, and this is my question: is it possible to change the color at call of the div? I.e. instead of having a single class with the same color or multiple copies of the same class with different colors, I would now like to change the color at the call of the div. Is it possible to do something like this:

```
<div class="triangle(red)"></div>
<div class="triangle(green)"></div>
<div class="triangle(light-red)"></div>
```

and so on for the various colors? I googled for variable usage in css and found some pages, but it seems to me that they are rather static, i.e. one defines them at the top or via js but then they are still hard-coded to the style definition, so they do not really change from div to div.

Thanks for any advice!

conni

Comment: Well, if i understand correctly you could create color classes (such as `.red`) that all they do is change color. Then, at the div decleration you will write this: `class="triangle red`.

Comment: Make a class for each colour. `.green{ background: green} .red { background: red} `. Then add to your class attribute like so: `<div class="triangle green"></div><div class="triangle red" ></div>`

Comment: consider CSS variable (example : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55091778/8620333)

Comment: No, you can't do that dynamically w/o script, or setting up static classes/variables. CSS is not a programming language, hence does not have methods one can run (other than `calc()` and `attr()` for now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "change the color at call of the div" you mean changing the color of the triangle at runtime, then no. HTML and CSS are not programming languages. You can, however,  create classes that just change the color to make your code semantic and reduce the amount of recycled code.

Some shapes allow you to do colors using the `background: color` property, but triangles are colored via the `border` property. For an upright triangle, you could do something like this:

```css
.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
}

.red {
  border-bottom: 50px solid red;
}

.green {
  border-bottom: 50px solid green;
}

.light-red {
  border-bottom: 50px solid #f78889;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle red"></div>
<div class="triangle green"></div>
<div class="triangle light-red"></div>
```

Note that this is actually quite popular for readability. This is the way bootstrap, semantic-ui, and many others do their styling, because you can look at the classes and see exactly what it is supposed to do. In the example above, you don't even need to see the executed code to know that you should expect a red triangle, a green triangle, and a light-red triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Use 4 CSS classes - 1 for the triangle and 3 more for each color.
As this triangle color comes from its `border-bottom`, apply the color by making a CSS like this: `.triangle.color-name {border-bottom-color: the-color;}`

```css
.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid #555;
}

.triangle.red {
  border-bottom-color: red;
}

.triangle.green {
  border-bottom-color: green;
}

.triangle.light-red {
  border-bottom-color: #f44;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle red">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="triangle green">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="triangle light-red">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your answers.
So it is not possible as I originally was hoping for (I wanted to avoid making x subclasses if I have x colors), but apparently there is no way around that.
Thank you!
conni